# DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body 0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required 1.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Tags: typescript, discord.js

while creating a slash command builder for a help command, it does not gets registered and gives the following error -

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
    0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    1.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
        at SequentialHandler.runRequest (P:\Backend\helpdesk-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:753:15)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (P:\Backend\helpdesk-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:565:14)
        at async REST.request (P:\Backend\helpdesk-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:999:22) {
      rawError: {
code: 50035,
    errors: { '0': [Object], '1': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/client_id/guilds/guild_id/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
}
```

i am creating a help command in a different file and exporting it via index.ts file
help.ts

```
export const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('help')
.setDescription('creates a new help ticket')
.addStringOption((option) =>
option
.setName('description')
.setDescription('describe your query')
.setRequired(true)
   );
export async function execute(interaction: CommandInteraction, client: Client) {
return interaction.reply('pong');
}
```

deploy command basically takes each file from command folders and adds it into the commands array. Now while making a basic ping pong command the commands get registered after running deploy-commands.ts, but after adding the help command it gives the above error
deploy-commands.ts

```
type Command = {
data: unknown;
};

const commands = [];

for (const module of Object.values<Command>(commandModules)) {
commands.push(module);
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(config.DISCORD_TOKEN);

rest
.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(config.CLIENT_ID, config.GUILD_ID), {
body: commands,
}).then(() => {
console.log('registered application commands');
})
.catch(console.error);
```